# Are there any museums or sites in Ireland honouring Lord Kelvin (William Thomson)?

Tags: ireland, museums, scotland, geek-travel, science

I'm travelling to the Republic of Ireland and Scotland from Australia and wanted to visit a number of sites of scientific history.

One at the top of my list is [Lord Kelvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Thomson,_1st_Baron_Kelvin). (He's important, apart from [measuring temperature,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin) because he invented the [first analog computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tide-predicting_machine)).

I'm aware there is a [display at the University of Glasgow](http://www.gla.ac.uk/hunterian/collections/permanentdisplays/lordkelvin/). He appears to have a [statue and a plaque](http://digital.nls.uk/scientists/biographies/lord-kelvin/places.html) in Belfast. He appears to have a [marking](http://digital.nls.uk/scientists/biographies/lord-kelvin/places.html) at Westminster Abbey. In Glasgow he appears to have a [memorial stone and a museum](http://digital.nls.uk/scientists/biographies/lord-kelvin/places.html).

My question is **Are there any museums or sites in Ireland honouring Lord Kelvin (William Thomson)?**

Comment: There seems to be plenty of people at the top of your list...

Comment: Scotland, Ireland and England produced a lot of amazing people, and when you're coming from Australia you need to make the trip worth it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have covered the options in your research. The [digital National Library of Scotland](http://digital.nls.uk/scientists/biographies/lord-kelvin/places.html) offers the following, from its collection, The Scientists:

> **
>   Lord Kelvin (1824-1907)**
>
> **Places to visit**
>
> Locations and visitor attractions associated with Lord Kelvin:
>
> **Belfast**
>
> [Belfast Botanic Gardens:](http://www.belfastcity.gov.uk/parksandopenspaces/parksdetails.asp?id=54)
>   Lord Kelvin statue
>
> [21-25 College Square East:](http://www.geograph.org.uk/photo/585982)
>   Plaque near Kelvin's birthplace.
>
> **Glasgow**
>
> [Hunterian Museum and Art Gallery:](http://www.hunterian.gla.ac.uk/)
>   The best place to learn about Kelvin and his work. An interactive display vividly illustrates many of his ideas and inventions.
>
> [Glasgow Necropolis:](http://www.glasgownecropolis.org/index.php?id=105)
>   Memorial stone to Lord Kelvin, unveiled in 2007 on the centenary of his death. The stone sits beside the Kelvin family gravestone, which also has an inscription to commemorate Lord Kelvin.
>
> **London**
>
> [Westminster Abbey:](http://www.westminster-abbey.org/)
>   Lord Kelvin's grave and memorial window.